# Cannot run python code using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52) to install the notebook on google cloud. It shows a wrong user interface and I cannot see blocks when I edit the file and cannot run either.

[image]

Comment: It turns out that I didn't "new a notebook”. It is a silly mistake. Can someone tell me if I should delete this question?

Comment: Instead of deleting I'll suggest you mark it as [SOLVED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that I open a .py file directly. Instead, we should create a new notebook by clicking `new`.

Comment: Reasonably informative, please mark this Solved (Accepted).